# How can you detect whether an iOS device supports push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I detect whether an iOS device has push notifications capability or not?

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]` tells what permissions the user has given.  I'm trying to figure out what capabilities the device has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1), push notifications was introduced in iOS 3.0.

That means that all i-devices which run iOS 3.0 or newer have that capability.

Both iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad, support the system because as others have noted, this is an OS feature, not a hardware feature.

So check if iOS is 3.0 or newer, or perhaps your software is targetting newer devices anyway, in which case you don't even have to check.

Answer (score 1):

All iOS Devices have Push Notifications as capability.

- iPad
- iPhone
- iPod Touch

This only relies on OS version and user settings. Not on hardware itself.

Comment: If it relies on the OS version, doesn't that imply that there might be some old versions that doesn't have the capability?

Comment: Well iOS <acoupleofyearsago> i should not be used anymore. all devices that exist can run an OS version that has APNS

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple Doc. you have no need to call a method to figure it out.

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs for short) is the centerpiece of the push notifications >feature. It is a robust and highly efficient service for propagating information to devices >such as iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html